# Preventing JSP with <textarea> from wrapping?

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I prevent IntelliJ from wrapping JSP code like this?

```
<textarea class="doh"><%=foo%></textarea>
```

After formatting, the closing tag is on the next line.

```
<textarea class="doh"><%=foo%>
</textarea>
```

If foo is an empty string then I get blank spaces in the textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File | Settings | Code Style | HTML | **Don't break if inline content**, add `textarea` to the list of tags.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work for the JSP script tags, please [watch/vote](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-63596) the issue in YouTrack.

Answer (score 0):

I would hate to have to resort to this, but the foo variable could include your html.  Though not ideal, it would get you past your problem.

Comment: I guess that's thinking outside the box.  For now, I'm just trying not to reformat the entire page.